# Invalid argument warning in my view class, why?

Tags: php, class

I get this :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \classes\classes.php on line 21

All my html goes in `$content[]` then I always use setContent first then render it. Whats causing this warrning, var_dumping $content says its an array, so why is the argument invalid? Should I just ignore this warning?

```
class cpage {
    private $title;
    private $content = array();

    public function __construct($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function __destruct() {

    }

    public function setContent($content) {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function render() {
        echo "<H1>{$this->title}</H1>";
    21:         foreach($this->content as $cont){
            echo $cont;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's because your `$this->content` isn't something, that is available for iterating through. Check this with `var_dump($this->content)` before cycle

Comment: You have the setting of the content in a function, but you're not calling the function in order to actually set it. You should call the setContent function in your construct.

Comment: @Ahmad, private are accessible inside the class. Is the variable an array in the first place?

Comment: I'm going to take a stab in the dark and say that this code: `$this->content = $content;` should be: `$this->content[] = $content;`.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in \classes\classes.php on line 21.

Comment: @Karl - this is how Im using this method. 
    <?php #index.php
    session_start();
    include 'classes/classes.php';
    include 'includes/stdlib.php';
     
    $site = new csite();
    initialise_site($site);
    $page = new cpage($_GET['page']);
    $site->setPage($page);

    $content = Controller::router($_GET['page']);

    $page->setContent($content);
    $site->render();
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message says that $this->content is not an array. You are setting it to a non-array value somewhere else in your code. The code sample you have provided has no errors, however I would suggest putting this in your setContent function:

```
if(!is_array($content)) throw new InvalidArgumentException("Content must be an array");
```

You can also use type hinting to solve this (thanks to RainFromHeaven for pointing it out).

You would declare the function like this:

```
public function setContent(array $content) {
    $this->content = $content;
}
```

Which will cause php to generate a PHP Catchable fatal error (`E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR`) if you try to pass it anything except an array. You can catch the error with set_error_handler.

Either of these will solve your problem, and which one you use is mostly a matter of personal preference. Usually I prefer exceptions, but I can certainly see how type hinting might make more sense here, as you most likely don't want to recover from the error.

Comment: @RainFromHeaven Very good point - I keep forgetting that php allows that now.

Comment: Can you give me more info on how type hinting would solve this?

Comment: Your `$this->content` is an array initially, so it has been set to something bad in your `setContent` function. If you use typehinting, forcing you to provide an array in that function , you'd get an error when calling it with a bad parameter. So you'd still have an error, but now one at the place you actually have mode one.

Answer (score 1):

If you force the setter to accept an array, you can trace which calling method is passing invalid data:

```
public function setContent(array $content) {
```

This assumes that `$content` should be an array - if you want to pass non-array items to be *added* to an array, then the method is probably misnamed anyway, and should be called something like `addItemToArray()` (as well as doing something different internally).